# Can't knit R markdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm trying to save an R Markdown file but keep getting this error message

```
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
  undefined exports: all_output_formats, beamer_presentation, clean_site, context_document, default_output_format, default_site_generator, draft, find_external_resources, find_pandoc, from_rmarkdown, github_document, html_dependency_bootstrap, html_dependency_font_awesome, html_dependency_highlightjs, html_dependency_ionicons, html_dependency_jquery, html_dependency_jqueryui, html_dependency_pagedtable, html_dependency_tocify, html_document, html_document_base, html_fragment, html_notebook, html_notebook_metadata, html_notebook_output_code, html_notebook_output_html, html_notebook_output_img, html_notebook_output_png, html_vignette, includes, includes_to_pandoc_args, ioslides_presentation, knit_params_ask, knitr_options, knitr_options_html, knitr_options_pdf, latex_dependency, latex_dependency_tikz, latex_document, latex_fragment, md_document, metadata, navbar_html, navbar_links_html, odt_document, output_format, output_metadata, paged_table, pandoc_available, pandoc_citeproc_ar
Calls: loadNamespace -> namespaceExport
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In loadNamespace(x) : package 'rmarkdown' has no 'package.rds' in Meta/
2: S3 methods 'knit_print.grouped_df', 'knit_print.rowwise_df', 'knit_print.tbl_sql', 'prepare_evaluate_output.default', 'prepare_evaluate_output.htmlwidget', 'prepare_evaluate_output.knit_asis', 'prepare_evaluate_output.list' were declared in NAMESPACE but not found 
Execution halted
```

Comment: What version of R are you running on what OS? What version of `rmarkdown` is installed?

Comment: I'm using R version 4.1.2 on Windows 10. I didn't know I need to install Rmarkdown. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: It appears you must have some version of rmarkdown already installed. You can install the latest version inside of R at the console with `install.packages("rmarkdown")`